# Write a program which takes a character string input and returns penultimate character. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: matlab

New to Matlab and using the an e-book to learn.

This was the question:

Write a MATLAB program which takes as its input a character string and print out its
penultimate character.

The code I worked out:

```
A=char('X');
X=input('Please enter a string of characters: ','s');
disp(X(Size-1));
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I run it, the input part happens and then I get an error, I assume this is due to incorrect index reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Size](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) is a function, not a variable. Therefore, it would need arguments, like `size(X)` which would return `[1 5]` for a 1x5 matrix.

Try `X(length(X)-1)` or more concisely, `X(end-1)`

More info:

- [`size(matrix)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) returns the dimensions of a matrix.
- `size(matrix, dimension)` returns the number of elements in a dimension (row, column, etc) of a matrix.
- [`numel(matrix)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) returns the number of elements of a matrix. For a 2D matrix, this is `#rows * #cols`. For any matrix, this is equivalent to `prod(size(matrix))`.
- [`length(matrix)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html) finds the number of elements along the largest dimension of a matrix. It is equivalent to `max(size(matrix))`

Comment: Thanks. It worked and now I need to read up on the difference. :) Cheers